# Codeigniter host errors after uploading website to the host

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling, hosting

I work with codeigniter framework. It's works fine in localhost and when I want to upload it to the host I get these errors:

(**Note:** I changed config.php and database.php in config file)

**First error:**

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Only variable references should be returned by reference

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 257
```

**Second one:**

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/emosbatc/domains/timit.ir/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 688
```

**Third one:**

```
Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/emosbatc/domains/timit.ir/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)

Filename: helpers/url_helper.php

Line Number: 542
```

What should I do? It's not the first one that I have problem after uploading to the host.

**Note:** Even my local php version is less than host version. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using an old version of codeigniter?

Comment: @Joerg yes, It's codeigniter 2. I think 2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three questions are :
- why this messages are shown ?
- why there is a difference of behaviour between development and production environment ?
- how to fix it ?

**The only relevant message is first**. The following messages are obtained simply because of the first: in sessions.php and URLs help, we try to send headers that must be sent before the response body, while the first message was generated (in the response body).

This message says that a **deprecated syntax is used**. The difference of behaviour between your two environments can be due to two things :
- you dont show messages in your development environment, but you show it in your production environment
- or more likely, since the code is not executed under the same version of PHP, **the problematic syntax is not considered as deprecated in your development environment**

To fix it, you will have to update your version of CodeIgniter (this has been fixed), or to directly fix the code.

To fix the code, I can only give you a generical solution, since I dont know which version you use exactly. In Common.php, you will probably find something like this piece of code :

```
return $_config[0] =& $config;
```

This is not rigorous because it means we try to return by reference, while the developer probably wanted to assign by reference then to return by value.
You can fix it with the minimum changes, by assigning and returning in two steps, by doing for example :

```
$_config[0] =& $config;
return $_config[0];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I searched first error and found your solution. But your explanation was really perfect and useful. Now again I have a question! Why returning like this: `return $_config[0];` solved the problem?